# In WPF is it possible to define a ControlTemplate for a UserControl inside the UserControl itself (without getting warnings/errors in VS)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, controltemplate

I have a UserControl I want to show with different control templates in some parts of a window. But I want to keep together these templates inside the UserControl itself (for a better maintaining). Here it is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PruebasDeWPF.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PruebasDeWPF"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="UserControlTemplate1" TargetType="local:MyUserControl">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red"></Rectangle>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="UserControlTemplate2" TargetType="local:MyUserControl">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue"></Rectangle>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

Now when I use it:

```
<Window x:Class="PruebasDeWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PruebasDeWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:MyUserControl Template="{StaticResource UserControlTemplate1}"></local:MyUserControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I get an error in Visual Studio saying resource could not be found and the control doesn't show up. If I change the template as a DynamicResource, I get the same message as a warning but the control shows. Anyway, the program runs fine. So how do I keep the UserControl and its templates together without getting these annoying warnings/errors? Do I need a specific ResourceDictionary (another file) for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you're trying to use isn't really suited to resources because of the way they are loaded: as a top down tree. To do switching between internally defined options it would be more appropriate to define a property on your `UserControl` (`DependencyProperty` if you want to bind it) which could indicate which of the available templates should be used. This could be a string, a number, or (probably the nicest option) an `enum` listing the available options. Inside your `UserControl` you can then switch the internally defined template used based on that value. This basic method is used for various framework controls - for example `Slider.Orientation`.

Comment: Ok, so I added a dependency property (enum in code behind) and a style (in xaml) to change the template based on that property value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do does not apply to a UserControl.

Try looking up articles for creating CustomControls.

Basically, you create a new class (just a class), inheriting from ContentControl, and use the property called "ContentTemplate" as you would use your "Template" property, in the code sample you provided.

If you have any specific logic to apply in your control, override the OnApplyTemplate method

Answer (score 0):

If you store the templates inside the control then I don't think you can use it as a StaticResource. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh758287.aspx

> Attempting to specify a StaticResource to a key that cannot resolve
>   throws a XAML parse exception at run time.

Your control doesn't exist during load time, so the template doesn't exist, so the reference to the template's non-existent key fails.

DynamicResources are only resolved at run time, which is why your program runs but with a warning. The warning in the designer is saying 'I can't find this now, but might be able to when the program's run'.